# Разворачивать определенный параметр js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой код:
**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var idsdfsd = $("#idpostcom").text();
    $("#idrcom-"+ idsdfsd).click(function(){
        $("#hidden-"+ idsdfsd).slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML|PHP**:

```
<div class='bottom'>
  $likeordislike - <a class='hider' id='idrcom-$posttid'>Комментарии ($clcomment[0])</a>
  <div class='cllike'>
    <span id='cllike-".$post[id]."'>$cllike[0]</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='blcomments' id='hidden-$posttid' style='display: none;'>
  $blmesscomments ". ((($clcomment[0] !== '0') AND ($posttid == $commentpost)) ? "$blcomments" : "") . "
  <div class='blgocomment' style='padding: 0px;'>
    <textarea placeholder='Оставить комментарий...' id='txtcom-$posttid'></textarea>
    <br />
    <div id='idpostcom' style='display: none;'>141</div>
    <a onclick='postComment($(this));' class='btnredprof' style='float: right; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;'>Добавить</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Это - слайдер (при нажатии на кнопку разворачивается контент).
Проблема в том, что таких html-блоков много, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии в блоке на кнопку выпадало именно под ним?

Я установил на каждый блок `id` (`$posttid`).

Попробовал реализовать таким образом:

```
$(document).ready(function hidercom(){
    $(".hider").click(function(){
        $("#hidden").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
<a class='hider' onClick='hidercom($(this));'>Комментарии ($clcomment[0])</a>
```

Всё равно не работает.

Comment: Наверное чтобы `id` на странице совпадал с `id` в скрипте

Comment: Учитесь пользоваться классами и относительной адресацией в jquery. В postComment вы $(this) передать догадались - так почему для клика какие-то монстро-айдишники генерируете?

Comment: @PavelMayorov исправил (в описании) всё равно не работает

Comment: Почему у вас повешено одновременно два обработчика?

Comment: И где вы используете относительную адресацию?

Comment: Ну а как будет сделать правильнее? Я не понимаю просто вообще...

Comment: @СашаОсипов, попробуйте так: `$(".hider").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next('.blcomments').slideToggle("slow");
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример реализации ниже. [https://jsfiddle.net/bearwolf/rj1enn6a/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/bearwolf/rj1enn6a/4/)

Параметр $(this) не нужно передавать в функцию. Он там уже есть по умолчанию.
Из моего опыта в js скриптах в событиях лучше использовать атрибуты или dat атрибуты.
Кстати плюс data атрибута в том что для него не нужно использовать parseInt или parseFloat. Эта функциональность реализована по умолчанию.

Стили я использую для css.

```js
  $('[data-type="showComments"]').click(function(){
  var _this = $(this);  
  _this.closest('.comments').find('.blcomments').slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
 
 $('textarea').on('keypress', function() {
  
  var max =  141,
   count,
   _this = $(this);

  count = max - _this.val().length;
  if (count <= 0) {
   count = 0;
   var text = _this.val().substring(0, max);
   _this.val(text);
  };
  _this.closest('.block-comment').find('.counter').text(count);
 }); 
 
 $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
  var _this = $(this);
  //post
  alert('Successfully');
  // saving
 });
```

```css
.comments{
 margin-bottom:15px;
}

.show-commnets{
 margin-left:20px;
 text-decoration:underline;
}

.block-comment{
}
.block-comment textarea{
 width:100px;
}
.counter{
 padding-left:80px;
 font-size:12px;
}

.blcomments{
 display:none;
 padding-top:10px;
}
.btnredprof{
 float: right;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='comments'>
 <a class='show-commnets' data-type='showComments'>Комментарии поста 1</a>
 <div class='blcomments'>
  <div class='blgocomment'>
   <form>
    <div class='block-comment'>
     <textarea placeholder='Оставить комментарий...'></textarea>
     <div class='counter'>141</div>    
    </div>
    <p><input type='submit' class='addComment' value='Добавить'></p>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class='comments'>
 <a class='show-commnets' data-type='showComments'>Комментарии поста 2</a>
 <div class='blcomments'>
  <div class='blgocomment'>
   <form>
    <div class='block-comment'>
     <textarea placeholder='Оставить комментарий...'></textarea>
     <div class='counter'>141</div>    
    </div>
    <p><input type='submit' class='addComment' value='Добавить'></p>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно написал @PavelMayorov, не нужны тут `id`, если представленный кусок кода просто повторяется много раз (не стал менять оригинальный код автора, тыкать нужно там где красная рамка):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hider").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.blcomments').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.hider {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #d32d36;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bottom'>
  $likeordislike - <a class='hider' id='idrcom-$posttid'>Комментарии ($clcomment[0])</a>
  <div class='cllike'>
    <span id='cllike-".$post[id]."'>$cllike[0]</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='blcomments' id='hidden-$posttid' style='display: none;'>
  $blmesscomments ". ((($clcomment[0] !== '0') AND ($posttid == $commentpost)) ? "$blcomments" : "") . "
  <div class='blgocomment' style='padding: 0px;'>
    <textarea placeholder='Оставить комментарий...' id='txtcom-$posttid'></textarea>
    <br />
    <div id='idpostcom' style='display: none;'>141</div>
    <a onclick='postComment($(this));' class='btnredprof' style='float: right; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;'>Добавить</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='bottom'>
  $likeordislike - <a class='hider' id='idrcom-$posttid'>Комментарии ($clcomment[0])</a>
  <div class='cllike'>
    <span id='cllike-".$post[id]."'>$cllike[0]</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='blcomments' id='hidden-$posttid' style='display: none;'>
  $blmesscomments ". ((($clcomment[0] !== '0') AND ($posttid == $commentpost)) ? "$blcomments" : "") . "
  <div class='blgocomment' style='padding: 0px;'>
    <textarea placeholder='Оставить комментарий...' id='txtcom-$posttid'></textarea>
    <br />
    <div id='idpostcom' style='display: none;'>141</div>
    <a onclick='postComment($(this));' class='btnredprof' style='float: right; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;'>Добавить</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='bottom'>
  $likeordislike - <a class='hider' id='idrcom-$posttid'>Комментарии ($clcomment[0])</a>
  <div class='cllike'>
    <span id='cllike-".$post[id]."'>$cllike[0]</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='blcomments' id='hidden-$posttid' style='display: none;'>
  $blmesscomments ". ((($clcomment[0] !== '0') AND ($posttid == $commentpost)) ? "$blcomments" : "") . "
  <div class='blgocomment' style='padding: 0px;'>
    <textarea placeholder='Оставить комментарий...' id='txtcom-$posttid'></textarea>
    <br />
    <div id='idpostcom' style='display: none;'>141</div>
    <a onclick='postComment($(this));' class='btnredprof' style='float: right; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;'>Добавить</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно при нажатии на .hider открывать #hidden

Comment: @СашаОсипов, `id='hidden-$posttid'` этот?

Answer (score -1):

Вместо `141` будет номер который уникальный для каждого блока.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".hider").click(function(){
    var idsdfsd = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#hidden-" + idsdfsd).slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='hider' id='141'>Комментарии ($clcomment[0])</div>

<div class='blcomments' id='hidden-141' style='display: none;'>
  <div class='blgocomment' style='padding: 0px;'>
    <textarea placeholder='Оставить комментарий...' id='txtcom-$posttid'></textarea>
    <br/>
    <a onclick='postComment($(this));' class='btnredprof' style='float: right; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;'>Добавить</a>
  </div>
```